# ESLintPlugin TS and JS Hybrid: ERROR in parent.eval is not a function

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, eslint, laravel-mix

##### Update

[This configuration](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test) works fine, if you remove the [ESLintPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin) from `webpack.mix.js`. The question now is: Where does it go wrong and why?

---

I'm trying to get TypeScript support on an existing Vue project. I would like to update gradually, keeping all the JavaScript code in place and using TypeScript for everything new or where there is a need for refactoring.

Currently, I'm stuck on a strange problem. Running with `npm run hot`:

```
$ npm run hot

> hot
> mix watch --hot

i Compiling Mix
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

// Some more warning from vuetify. They are not important right now.

√ Mix: Compiled with some errors in 7.29s
ERROR in parent.eval is not a function
Occurred while linting C:\fakepath\ts-test\resources\js\app.ts:7

webpack compiled with 1 error
No issues found.
```

Unfortunately, I can't find anything regarding this error `ERROR in parent.eval is not a function`.

Even weirder is, that every time I re-write the `tsconfig.json` it works fine:

```
i Compiling Mix


   Laravel Mix v6.0.31


✔ Compiled Successfully in 201ms
┌───────────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│                              File │ Size      │
├───────────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│                    /some/files.js │  X.X KiB  │
└───────────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
√ Mix: Compiled successfully in 252.23ms
webpack compiled successfully
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
```

Because this issue involves way too many config files, to reasonably post here, I created a small GitHub project:

https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test

The files to look at, are probably:

- [`webpack.mix.js`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/webpack.mix.js)
- [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/tsconfig.json)
- [`.eslintrc.js`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/.eslintrc.js)

---

##### Some things to note:

1. I have to use `// @ts-ignore` in [`App.vue line 51`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/views/App.vue), because eslint is trying to type check the vue file, even if the script tag is not `lang="ts"`.

```
ERROR in resources/js/views/App.vue:51:12
TS2339: Property '$vuetify' does not exist on type '{ changeTheme(): void; }'.
  49 |       // });
  50 |
> 51 |       this.$vuetify.theme.dark = !this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
     |            ^^^^^^^^
  52 |     }
  53 |   },
```

I thought this file shouldn't be validated from TS, because of my [`.eslintrc.js`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/.eslintrc.js). Why isn't this working as intendet? (Documentation [vue-eslint-parser#parseroptionsparser](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-eslint-parser#parseroptionsparser))

2. Type validation isn't working in [`testts.vue`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/components/testts.vue). I set the props in [`App.vue`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/views/App.vue), and from my understanding at least one of them, if not both, have to raise a type error for the [`testts.vue`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/components/testts.vue) component.

From [`testts.vue`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/components/testts.vue):

```
props: {
    testprop: {
        type: Object as PropType<TestType>,
        required: true
    }
},
```

In [`App.vue`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/views/App.vue):

```
<TestTS :testprop="{name: 'testts', id: '2'}"></TestTS>
<TestTS :testprop="{blub: 'bla', id: '3'}"></TestTS>
```

And [`testtype.ts`](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/blob/master/resources/js/types/testtype.ts)

```
export default interface TestType {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the problem to `node_modules/prettier/third-party.js` line 94.

Then I found out, that I have `prettier@2.0.0` installed and not the newest version.

In the end I changed this in the `package.json` in [this commit](https://github.com/Darkproduct/vue2-ts-test/commit/80259986402dba076da28ed75b9589502ab92944):

```
-       "prettier": "2.0.0",
+       "prettier": "^2.4.1",
```

This fixes the error: parent.eval is not a function